# Splitting matrix multiplication using einsum

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, numpy-einsum

I have a large data matrix and I want calculate the similarity matrix of that large matrix but due to memory limitation I want to split the calculation.

Lets assume I have following: For the example I have taken a smaller matrix

```
data1 = data/np.linalg.norm(data,axis=1)[:,None]

(Pdb) data1
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , ...,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.04777415,  0.00091094,  0.01326067, ...,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ],
       ...,
       [ 0.        ,  0.01503281,  0.00655707, ...,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.00418038,  0.00308079,  0.01893477, ...,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.06883803,  0.        ,  0.0209448 , ...,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

They I try to do following:

```
similarity_matrix[n1:n2,m1:m2] = np.einsum('ik,jk->ij', data1[n1:n2,:], data1[m1:m2,:])
```

n1,n2,m1,m2 been calculated as follows: (df is a data frame)

```
data = df.values
m, k = data.shape
n1=0; n2=m/2; m1=n2+1; m2=m;
```

But the error is:

```
(Pdb) similarity_matrix[n1:n2,m1:m2] = np.einsum('ik,jk->ij', data1[n1:n2,:], data1[m1:m2,:])
*** NameError: name 'similarity_matrix' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't you do something like

```
similarity_matrix = np.empty((N,M),dtype=float)
```

at the start of your calculations?

You can't index an array, on right or left side of an equation, before you create it.

If that full `(N,M)` matrix is too big for memory, then just assign your `einsum` value to another variable, and work with that.

```
partial_matrix = np.einsum...
```

How you relate that `partial_matrix` to the virtual `similarity_matrix` is a different issue.